# jQuery is not a function when using .has()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this simple jQuery code

```
function removePreloader() {
    jQuery('ul.woocommerce-error').has('li').jQuery("#preloader").css("display", "hidden");
}
```

and it's being called by

```
jQuery('form[name="checkout"]').submit(function(e) {
    ... // lots of line
    setTimeout(removePreloader(), 2000);
}
```

both block of codes is inside `jQuery(document).ready(function() { ... });`

the other `jQuery()` is working fine, only this one is causing a problem and showing

> Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).has(...).jQuery is not a function

is it not possible to use `.has`? or is there any alternate? because this wordpress theme using a lot of old plugin, so they can't accept newer version of jQuery.

Thank you

here is the screenshot from `jquery.com`

[image]

I just trying to follow this javascript and modified it a little bit, please let me know how to do this the right way, because I don't never code with javascript before

Comment: This is invalid jQuery statement `jQuery('ul.woocommerce-error').has('li').jQuery("#preloader").css("display", "hidden");` what you want to achieve?

Comment: what is your version of jQuery? .has started in 1.4 - looks like they are trying to hide something when there is a woo commerce error

Comment: The random `jQuery` in this line: `....has('li').jQuery("#preloader").css(...` is causing the problem. What are you expecting it to do? Did you mean `find()` instead?

Comment: I want to make the `preloader` disappear when there's an error added to `ul.woocommerce-error`, the error will be in `li` tag, so what I want is if the woocommerce-error has li child, then preloader div display is hidden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using an invalid jQuery statement `.jQuery...`, I would suggest the use of the `if` statement when checking if there are any `li` children inside the list like :

```
function removePreloader() {
    if( jQuery('ul.woocommerce-error li').length ){
       jQuery("#preloader").css("display", "none");
    }
}
```

**NOTE 1:** `display` property has no `hidden` value, so you're searching for `none` instead.

**NOTE 2:** Remove the `()` in the function call like :

```
setTimeout(removePreloader, 2000);
```

Comment: I just tried using your solution, but it doesn't working, I even put `alert()` to make sure that the if condition is true, and because it doesn't work, I make a change to this one `jQuery('ul.woocommerce-error li').length > 0`, but still no luck

Comment: add the alert before the `if` to make sure the `removePreloader()` is reached.

Comment: `setTimeout(removePreloader(), 2000);` must be `setTimeout(removePreloader, 2000);` instead, note removing `()`

Comment: ah I see, that's where I wrong, that's why it doesn't work, thank you

Answer (score 1):

> Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).has(...).jQuery is not a function

means `.jQuery` is not a function on the returned object of `.has()`. That also means `.has()` works just fine here. Try to use [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) instead.

Comment: @Pete not true, `has()` returns a jQuery object

Comment: @Pete No? it returns a jquery object `Description: Reduce the set of matched elements to those that have a descendant that matches the selector or DOM element.`

Comment: Hi I wanted to try using your solution, is the `find()` returns a bool as well?

Comment: @KhrisnaGunanasurya No. `.find()` returns the matched set of elements just like `jQuery()` does and probably what you expected it to do here.